# MySQL Workbench: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1' (10061)" error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I apologise.. I know this question has been asked many times before, but I've tried lots of suggestions, and simply can't find a solution.

The problem:  I have a MySQL database running on a hosted server.
I have to use SSH to connect to it, and I have the relevant Public and Private Key files.

I specifically want to use the PC version of *MySQL Workbench*, to access this database, for running queries, checking data, etc.

If I run **Sequel Pro** on a Mac, it connects fine, and I can browse and query the database.  No problems.

If I run the trial version of **SQLyog** on a PC, it also connects fine.  No problems.

But if I try to connect use MySQL's own "**MySQL Workbench**" application, using exactly the same settings and SSH Private Key file, it refuses to connect, throwing the well-known error:

**Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1' (10061)**

I find it frustrating, as, in SQL Workbench, I specified the "MySQL Hostname" to use, *db01.mysql.vm.MyHostingServer.net*, but Workbench seems to ignore it, and demand to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead.

(I have read that Workbench says it needs the Public key file, but actually means the Private key file... and I have tried with both.  I've also tried with *MySQL Workbench* on a Mac, but that crashed all over the place, simply when I was typing in server names and passwords..  it was a mess !!)

The hosting service I've gone with gives me limited permissions for changing MySQL settings, and given that Sequel Pro and SQLyog *can* connect successfully, I don't want to start messing about and changing things randomly.

Any ideas...?

Comment: Which version of MySQL workbench are you using?

Comment: Yes, you should be more explicit as to what WB version are you using, the local and remote OSes and the exact steps you are following to set up your server instance in Workbench. Without that it would be very difficult to help you.

Comment: Sorry..  I'm using version: "MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE", v5.2.36 CE, revision 8542.  This was the most recent version available in December 2011.   The reason I didn't quote this is that many many other web articles report this error, it's not a new issue.... but none of the recommended solutions has worked for me.

Comment: type mysql at the command line and report what happens

Answer (score 16):

Maybe you are not allowed to start the service "MySQL 55". Set the login information of Service "MySQL 55" as local!

[image]

To see the list of aviable services in Windows 7:

1. Open a run box [image]
2. Type `services.msc` and press return.
3. Find the service `MySQL55`
4. A right click of the MySQL55 Local Service shows Properties -> Log On [image][image]

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer step by step..??? for window 7.. thanks in advance

Comment: i have started sql workbench and it is showing as a running program and process in task manager but not in services

Answer (score 4):

Even I had same problem, The reason was mysql service was not getting configured properly, when I installed it through 'MySQL installer'. Also it was not starting, when I tried to start the service manually.

So in my case it seemed be a Bug with the 'MySQL Installer', as editing the install path to a different one when the 'Developer default' was selected, the problem occurs.

Solution (Not exactly a solution):

- Uninstalled the MySQL all products (completely)
- Reinstalled, this time also I have selected 'Developer default', but didn't make any changes to the path or any thing. So the path was just 'C:\Program Files\MySQL' (the default one)
- And just clicked Next Next...
- Done, this time MySql was running fine.

Answer (score 1):

After making above improvement such as checking if `mysql service` is **running** or not, you just need to give a small password while creating connection, it is `' '` or 1 time press on space-bar in case of GUI or workbench. After which you just need to validate your machine with server (validated HOST). For that purpose click on `'New Server Instance'` and it will configure server/HOST on your behalf itself.

I have done this *successfully* just a few couple of minutes ago. My workbench software is able to *show* all `pre-installed databases` etc now.

hope it will work for you as well.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the host name (`db01.mysql.vm.MyHostingServer.net`) in your windows host (`C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\host`) file along with it's IP address and port number and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...  but no, even after a reboot, there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a new server, you click on home + add new connection. Put IP or webserver URL in new connection.

[image: how to create]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the following command manually:

```
C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysqld.exe --console
```

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exact same problem as OP and found that leaving the "MySQL Server Port" empty in the MySQL Workbench connection solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the method.
I will suggest you to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue, way i have resolved is:

opened the MySQL installer. i was having a Reconfigure link on MYSQL Server row.
[image: MYSQL Server having Reconfigure Link]

Clicked on it, it does reinstalled MySQL Server.
after that opened MySQL Workbench, and it was working fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you have installed WAMP on your machine, please make sure that it is running. Do not EXIT the WAMP from tray menu since it will stop the MySQL Server.