# Using MySQL workbench I can't create new connections

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a freshly installed workbench 6.3 version and a 5.1 mysql Server version.

I already have connections created. Namely, I can successfully connecto to local Instance MySQL56, which I assume is a default connection. I have two, way older connections that have appeared even though last time I used this program (and later uninstalled) was months ago, with another version.

I've read what I've found and felt could help

[MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE, Windows 7, "Can't connect to MySQL Server on 127.0.0.1 (10061)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227037/mysql-workbench-5-2-ce-windows-7-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1)

[MySQL Workbench: "Can't connect to MySQL server on 127.0.0.1' (10061)" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832116/mysql-workbench-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-127-0-0-1-10061-error)

And tried every option. Nothing works. I try to create a connection with this steps:

Database -> manage connections -> bottom left corner: New

Then I give it a name, leave everything as default, put a pw into the vault, and try to test it. Does not work. Whatever combination I try, it does not work. Yes server is running, I've tried 3 different ways of checking.

I do not understand at all how something I've done in the past is taking me so many hours, I do not know what I'm missing, but I can't create a new connection.

Also to be noted, in case it's useful: On default schema, I write the name of a schema I previously created. Thing is, as I said, I've tried every combination. But when I've tried to save said schema in a folder, workbench has instantly crashed. Twice already.

I'm all out of ideas, so if anyone can tell me what to do, it'd be of great help, I find nothing following guides out there.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @MikeLischke cannot connect to database server: your connection failed for user 'root' from your host to server ..... Access denied for user root@localhost (using password: YES).||I've tried changing user, different passwords, looking for people with similar problems in the past... don't know where to look.

Comment: You mention MySQL server 5.1 but with a service named MySQL56, are there multiple MySQL servers running? Right-click on the home screen and choose "Rescan for local MySQL instances" and see what happens.

Comment: A message appears saying: Found 1 servers. Not sure how helpful that is but that's what shows @PhilipOlson